# Segment Fault with rails runner (Rails 4.0.0 Ruby 2.2.2p95 CentOS7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, centos7

This error is completely beyond me and if it needs to be put somewhere else, please let me know.  For similar reasons I also don't know what is in the 'scope' of this problem, so if you need anymore information please let me know.

As far as I can tell, the command does run, but immediately after it throws a segment fault error.  As far as I can tell there is no indicator as to why or what was wrong.  There are a few warnings being thrown but most have existed for a while without this error.

```
bin/rails runner -eproduction 'puts 1'
/var/www/projects/cdops4/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
[DEPRECATION] requiring "RMagick" is deprecated. Use "rmagick" instead
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /var/www/projects/cdops4/releases/1430760842/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
/var/www/projects/cdops4/releases/1430760842/app/jobs/parser/taske_parser.rb:132: warning: duplicated key at line 136 ignored: :queue
/var/www/projects/cdops4/releases/1430760842/app/jobs/parser/taske_parser.rb:134: warning: duplicated key at line 149 ignored: :hit_t2
/var/www/projects/cdops4/releases/1430760842/lib/taske_parser.rb:319: warning: duplicated key at line 321 ignored: :t1_wrap_time
1
[BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x00000000000018
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-linux]

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007f459d8a1c00 RBP: 0x00007fff3bc4b570 RSP: 0x00007fff3bc4b1e8
 RAX: 0x0000000000000000 RBX: 0x0000000004fd6b30 RCX: 0x0000000000000000
 RDX: 0x0000000000000001 RDI: 0x0000000000000008 RSI: 0x0000000000000080
  R8: 0x0000000000000000  R9: 0x00000000000000ca R10: 0x00007fff3bc4af70
 R11: 0x00007f459d8a1c00 R12: 0x00007f45868c4bc8 R13: 0x000000000000003d
 R14: 0x0000000000000001 R15: 0x00007fff3bc4b210 EFL: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/libruby.so.2.2(rb_vm_bugreport+0x51f) [0x7f459dca1fdf] vm_dump.c:693
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/libruby.so.2.2(rb_bug_context+0xcb) [0x7f459db35efb] error.c:425
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/libruby.so.2.2(sigsegv+0x3e) [0x7f459dc158fe] signal.c:879
/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x7f459d8a7130]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0 [0x7f459d8a1c00]
/lib64/libtspi.so.1(host_table_final+0x14) [0x7f458667abb4]
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(_dl_fini+0x1ca) [0x7f459dfa7b5a]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__run_exit_handlers+0xd9) [0x7f459cdc0e49]
/lib64/libc.so.6 [0x7f459cdc0e95]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfc) [0x7f459cda9afc]
[0x4008e9]

**Removed Memory map, stackoverflow wouldn't let me submit with it**    

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted
```

---

So I feel like this has caused some confusion, but I'm not trying to fix the log file.  Its redirecting to standard output and all is fine there.

The issue seems to be within tiny_tds.  Removing the gem and retrying prevented the error in a new project.  Attempting this on my original project crashes (because the project requires it).

At this point it seems like the problem exists somewhere between Ruby and the tiny_tds gem's libs.

Comment: Generally speaking, it's supposed to be impossible to get segfaults in pure Ruby code. Unless there's some Ruby library written in C that's crashing (perchaps rmagick?), this is a bug in the Ruby interpreter. Reduce the problem to a small, reproducible example, then do what the error messages says and submit a bug report to http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html. (Or if it turns out the problem is with rmagick, submit it to https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/issues)

Comment: Ok, I'll try to drill down where the problem is occurring.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: here is what another question says about log file permissions problems.: "what's setting your permissions back to default is probably logrotate, so check out your logrotate config and find the stanza that's doing your /var/log/messages rotation and change it."   The same considerations exist for production.log.

Comment: the messages say to fix the permission on the log file.  The messages say to change a 'require' statement.  The messages say to fix the code (two places)  Handle these items and the warnings will go away.

Comment: if you cannot correct the problem,  post the source on pastebin.com and update the question to include a link to the pastebin entry.  Then we can debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally found the source of the problem.  We were using a gem called tiny_tds and as far as I can tell, this gem will not work with centOS 7.  All issues resolved once it was removed and redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

here is what another answer says about permissions on log files:

Hope this helps

Begin Quote:

The directory should be 750, not 664. Also, you should add the user to the adm group. That's actually largely the point of the adm group: reading logs.

Permissions on directories are a bit different than on files. To simplify a bunch, a directory is a list of names and addresses: the name is the filename, the address is the actual location of the file. The x permission controls access to this list: in order to look up the address of a specific file, you need the execute bit on its parent directory, and on that directory's parent, etc. The r permission then controls listing files: If you have --x, you can access a file if you know its name, but you can't ls. Lastly, w controls creating, renaming, and deleting files. So, in order to access a file, you always need the x bit.

Also: DON'T set the log files to  777. They should be 644 or 640, one of the two. Two reasons: one, they're not executable, so the x bit should be off. Second, more importantly, normal users should never be writing to Apache log files, only reading. That's a potential security hole in the server.

End Quote: